# Component not re-rendering when updating state within map function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-state

I don't know why the component isn't re-rendering automatically when I click on the button that runs the function `update`.  I see that the after click on the button, the state updates but the list does not automatically re-render.  Isn't the component supposed to re-render when `setFoobar` is called?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const SomeList = () => {
  const [foobar, setFoobar] = useState([
    {
      description: "description1",
      date: "date1",
    },
    {
      description: "description2",
      date: "date2",
    },
  ]);
  const update = () => {
    const newFoobar = foobar;
    newFoobar.push({
      description: "This new item should render in view",
      date: "asdf",
    });
    setFoobar(newFoobar);
  };
  const generateList = foobar((each, idx) => {
    return (
      <div key={idx}>
        <div>{each.description}</div>
        <div>{each.date}</div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={update}>Click</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return <div>{generateList}</div>;
};

export default SomeList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because `const newFoobar = foobar;`, the previous state and new state is same object so the component will not re-render. So you have to create a new object and update it

```
const update = () => {
    const newFoobar = [...foobar];
    newFoobar.push({
      description: "This new item should render in view",
      date: "asdf",
    });
    setFoobar(footer);
  };
```

Comment: Oops, I made a typo while writing this post.  I fixed the typo.  My issue is that the state gets updated, but it doesn't render the component with the new state values, until another setState is triggered elsewhere.  I'm trying to figure out why this logic doesn't trigger re-render automatically.

Comment: Actually, it's working, it turns out that spread syntax was necessary for the re-render.  Thank you!